# Which of these snippets use less resources?

Tags: resources, python-3.4, processing-efficiency

I have these 3 ways of displaying a moving bar to indicate that the program is still running even though it has no output at the moment.  Because this program has the potential to become very involved and use a lot of resources I and tweaking every component I can for resource efficiency.  My question is which is most resource efficient?

snippet 1, an ugly string of if statements:

```
spinner = 0
while True:
    .
    #do some work
    .
    sleep(5)
    spinner += 1
    if spinner == 11: spinner = 0
    #-----end of common code------    
    if spinner == 1: print('          \r' + '█', end='\r')
    if spinner == 2: print('██', end='\r')
    if spinner == 3: print('███', end='\r')
    if spinner == 4: print('████', end='\r')
    if spinner == 5: print('█████', end='\r')
    if spinner == 6: print('██████', end='\r')
    if spinner == 7: print('███████', end='\r')
    if spinner == 8: print('████████', end='\r')
    if spinner == 9: print('█████████', end='\r')
    if spinner == 10: print('██████████', end='\r')
```

snippet 2, a prettier bit of code, but a lot more calls to the print() function:

```
    bar = 0
    print('             ', end='\r')
    while bar < (spinner + 1):
        print('█', end='')
        bar += 1
```

snippet 3, another pretty bit of code with different resource uses...

```
block = '█'
print('               \r' + block * spinner, end='\r')
```

I was originally using a spinner to do this by printing |, /, -, and \, but I could not see it well from my workstation on the server across the room, so I changed it to this bar method. BTW, that's why the variable is named 'spinner'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I'll answer my own question.  I did some benchmark timing on these three snippets and took the average of 1 million iterations through each one. As you can imagine the numbers were tiny. Snippets 1 and 3 were not significantly different. Snippet 2, as I suspected was slower by about 10%. So I have decided to go with snippet 3.  Given that it has fewer lines of code, that's a few bits off the HDD and the RAM.  I'll take what I can get!